# Python "Failed to install packages" error

Tags: python, package, pycharm, failed-installation

I am using Pycharm as my IDE and I am encountering an error while attempting to install pandas. I have provided images of my Python and pip versions and my python interpreters for reference.
[image of python and pip versions. -->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO05O.png)
[image of the python interpeters. -->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHL1s.png)
[image of venv interpeter (it seemed awkward so i posted it)-->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9LFH.png),
The error message I am receiving is as follows:

````
  Using cached pandas-2.0.2.tar.gz (5.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [76 lines of output]
  Collecting setuptools>=61.0.0
    Using cached setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.33
    Using cached Cython-0.29.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
  Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16
    Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
  Collecting versioneer[toml]
    Using cached versioneer-0.28-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.19.3
    Using cached numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
    Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
  
    [40 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\90538\PycharmProjects\CSV\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\90538\PycharmProjects\CSV\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\Users\90538\PycharmProjects\CSV\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        backend = _build_backend()
      File "C:\Users\90538\PycharmProjects\CSV\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
        obj = import_module(mod_path)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\90538\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnvi2xem\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 253, in <module>
        monkey.patch_all()
      File "C:\Users\90538\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnvi2xem\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 101, in patch_all
        patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\90538\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnvi2xem\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 164, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
        patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
      File "C:\Users\90538\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnvi2xem\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 151, in patch_params
        mod = import_module(mod_name)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\90538\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nnvi2xem\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
    [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  
  [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
  [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip```
Thank you for your help
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by deleting mingw64 python files, and deleting pycharm completely. then i downloaded again and pycharm automatically get me interpeter. if you are having same problem just delete all python versions from your pc and pycharm too. then download pycharm again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upgrade pip?

```
pip install --upgrade pip

# or if using pip3
pip3 install --upgrade pip

# if you don't have pip in PATH
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# or
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If it is not enough, try to upgrade wheels as well:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

# or
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools wheel

# if you don't have pip in PATH
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

# or
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
```

Comment: Yes i have tried it, all of them says "Requirement already satisfied".

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages (23.1.2)" it says exactly this maybe this helps